# What's the Rubygems / Packagist equivalent for Android?

Tags: java, android

Excluding Github, where I can find a repo directory like Rubygems / Packagist for Android ?

Comment: Heve you check mercurial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the previous answer is right. Any maven repository can be used with Gradle and hence they are good places to get dependencies from.

If you are not familiar with gradles dependency management mechanisms, you'll find further information in the [tutorial on gradle.org](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html).

But if you are looking for a web interface to search for some android specific libraries, you might have a look at [Android Arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com).

Comment: What about http://gradleplease.appspot.com which features package search & gradle instructions ?

Comment: That page is good for the automatic generation of the *gradle dependency line*, when you are knowing the package you want to include. The results of that page came from Maven Central (search.maven.org), so its just a lighter interface for that page. However, I think, it is better to use search.maven.org hence you got information about all versions of a library, the update time and so on (so its better for finding new libraries). But if you have a well known library and you just want to get the gradle code, *Gradle, please* might be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Android Arsenal is the best place if your looking for libraries

https://android-arsenal.com/

Answer (score 1):

Gradle is the default dependency management system for Android and it uses the Maven Central Repository to find remote dependencies. You can look at this repo on http://search.maven.org/. For more information about it: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-build.html#dependencies